# Working around a pygame trigonometry error

Tags: python, pygame

I'm making a pygame game designed so that bullets will shoot in the direction of the mouse. I'm using 
a Class to define the bullets in a list like this:

```
class Bullet:
    def __init__(self,pos,speed,size):
        self.pos = pos
        self.speed = speed
        self.size = size
    def move(self):
        self.pos[0] = int(self.pos[0] + self.speed[0])
        self.pos[1] = int(self.pos[1] + self.speed[1])
```

I'm using this trigonometry function to get the vector of the angle in which I'm going to be shooting bullets.

```
def getUnitVector(x1, y1, x2, y2):
        delx = x2 - x1
        dely = y2 - y1
        m = math.sqrt(delx * delx + dely * dely)
        unit = (delx / m, dely / m)
        return unit
level = [
```

I'm not using angles because I have to work around a pygame rounding error.
these are the variables I'm plugging into the function.

```
mousex, mousey = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    startx = 50
    starty = 400
aim = getUnitVector(startx, starty, mousex, mouse
```

This how i'm handling the aim and making the bullets shoot from the start x,y

```
if pygame.mouse.get_pressed()[0]:
        if reload>10:
            bx = BULLETSPEED * aim[0]
            by = BULLETSPEED * aim[1]           
            bullet = Bullet([startx,starty], [bx,by],10)
            bullets.append(bullet)
            reload=0
        reload = reload + 1
```

I just want to let you know. I'm working on a school assignment and I will be learning more in depth about vectors and trig next unit so I don't really want to spend too much time learning this stuff right now :L . Also if you know any active python forums that might be more helpful in answer this question please comment. I cant find any.
Thank you for your time.

I might just build a work-around by only allowing it to shoot if the mouse is within 20 pixels or something so the error is minimized.

Comment: We're not going to look through a codedump and fix your code for you with no effort on your part. Please only post the relevant code, and elaborate on the problem; "not shooting straight" is not helpful at all.

Comment: Please do not post your whole code. Try to reduce the code to the minimum required to reproduce the problem

Comment: Also, the problem is with your physics calculation. Rethink your method again.

Comment: Ok I'll try a few more things, sorry.

Comment: Should I just delete this post and redo it?

Comment: No, why would you do that?

Comment: Well, as it is the post stands a good chance of being closed, and editing takes some time, so deleting and later reposting seems an option

Comment: @HugoRune Why would it be locked? That is only for questions with historical significance. Deleting and reposting is a bad idea; it may contribute to a question ban and there is no reason to do that.

Comment: @Doorknob of Snow bad choice of terms, I meant *closed/put on hold*, not *locked*, I edited my previous post to reflect that. Closed questions or negative-score questions can also contribute to a ban, but it takes a little more than just one question. (@Trows no worries, this is your first question after all)

Comment: So can you give me a hint or something as to how I screwed up the physics? one second I'm going to edit the question to make it neater.

Comment: @Trows I just saw that this actually is not your first question, apparently this is the third time you posted [pretty much the same question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20713351/145999) in the last days. Don't do that.

Comment: Ok, I edited it and I hopefully made it more appropriate, I should have read some other posts before asking a question. sorry.

Comment: @HugoRune I really suck at asking specific questions when it comes to programming since i'm still so new I think i'm afraid of confusing people.

Comment: OK, deleting your last question is really confusing matters now, step away from that delete button. I think I saw you got a good hint in the comments last time, but I cannot verify that now anymore, did you check out that hint already?

Comment: I was just about to submit an answer when this question was closed. Never mind. Here is what I was going to post: http://pastebin.com/uAzrF41N

Trows, you might have more luck asking these sorts of questions on sites for beginner game developers. I imagine there must be a lot of such sites out there.

Comment: @Dangph Though this isn't the greatest question, I voted to reopen because of that answer. You should definitely post it if this gets reopened.

Comment: Also, I don't know what's wrong but that didn't seem to work, read the new question :L

Comment: @Trows, it looks like that if you had a question, it got lost in your edit.  Please edit in an actual question.

Comment: @Dangph, it has been reopened, you can post the answer now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bullet class should have a rectangle attribute so that the bullet's direction of travel runs through the bullet's center.

Doing this would first require reading the Pygame documentation here: [Pygame.Rect Docs](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html)

Centering the bullet rectangle on the direction of travel could be implemented in a movement method as such:

```
    def move(self):
        self.dir = self.get_direction(self.target) # get direction
        if self.dir: # if there is a direction to move

            self.trueX += (self.dir[0] * self.speed) # calculate speed from direction to move and speed constant
            self.trueY += (self.dir[1] * self.speed)
            self.rect.center = (round(self.trueX),round(self.trueY)) # apply values to bullet.rect.center
```

More information can be found in this helpful sprite movement example:[Pygame Sprite Movement](http://www.pygame.org/project-Sprite+Movement+Towards+a+Target-1538-.html)